# Simulation of QED

Tags: specific-reference, standard-model, research-level, quantum-electrodynamics, simulations

Can anyone point me to a paper dealing with simulation of QED or the Standard Model in general? I will particularly appreciate a review paper.

Answer (score 6):

Is there a reason that you are interested in QED in particular? For processes within current experimental ranges, the standard perturbative treatment is incredibly accurate, and simulations are not really necessary.

A sector of the standard model where simulations are incredibly important is in strong interactions (QCD) for which a perturbative treatment is not satisfactory as one heads to the IR (low energy). A good reference to start at could be: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0506036

Comment: I've looked for the same thing and the only thing you find is a lot of lattice QCD talk normally, so I second the question and it would be especially interesting to hear if for example it is impossible or very impractical to simulate QED in the same way for fundamental reasons (the fact that there are other methods currently giving better results for some classes of problem formulations is another issue, IMO). Anyway, interesting introduction you linked!

Comment: @BjornWesen:  It's not impossible to simulate QED on a lattice.  It's actually quite a bit easier than simulating QCD.  But it's rather pointless, because the perturbative approximation is so good.

Comment: Nevertheless, I still haven't found any good description of it.. if it really is that more simple than lattice qcd, then you'd expect some descriptions to exist, if nothing else than to "warm up" the reader to lattice qcd..

Answer (score 2):

The Standard Model theoretical first and second order terms plus QCD approximations are input  as [generators](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2927) for the Monte Carlo simulations for the LHC data :

> Most of the emphasis is on the simulation of events that contain a hard process, although I
>   will return to mention minimum bias collisions later. Since the hard interaction is generally the
>   process of interest it acts as the trigger around which the simulation of the whole event is built.
>   In the previous generation of simulation these were almost always 2 : 2 processes, but one of
>   the largest areas of development in recent years, which I will describe in detail below, has been
>   the inclusion of higher order corrections, both in terms of multi-parton tree-level processes and
>   also NLO corrections to the low parton multiplicity processes.

These Monte Carlos have in addition as input the description of the detector and the processes that prescribe the tracks and hits to simulate   the signals of the interaction  in the detector.

Keep in mind that in high energy physics the Monte Carlo method is an integration method, convoluting all the inputs, theoretical and detector dependent. Events are generated as if they are real events and a data base is created which is studied and compared to the real data.